# .htaccess 301 rediect going to root

Tags: php, regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

i am trying to use .htaccess 301 redirect but its not working

i am using following syntax in my .htaccess file

```
RewriteRule ^our_services.html http://localhost/site/our-services [R=301,L]
```

but when i open the page page redirect to

```
http://localhost/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/site/our-services
```

how to write correct one ?

i want to redirect

```
our_services.html to our-services
```

in same domain

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you try relative paths like this:

If in `DOCUMENT_ROOT`:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^our_services\.html$ /our-services [R=301,L,NC]
```

If in `DOCUMENT_ROOT/site`:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /site/

RewriteRule ^our_services\.html$ our-services [R=301,L,NC]
```

Comment: OK can you tell me location of this htaccess file?

Comment: it work with RedirectMatch 301 but i want to use RewriteRule, i think RewriteRule is batter for seo

Comment: Is this `.htaccess` in `DOCUMENT_ROOT` or `DOCUMENT_ROOT/site`?

Comment: I have provided both versions, please try and **make sure that this rule is first rule before any other CI rule**

Comment: thanks for all help but its not working , as i said RedirectMatch 301 is working but RewriteRule not working...

Comment: You should really help yourself first by providing as much details as possible. `RedirectMatch` is a different module `mod_alias` and has no connection with `mod_rewrite`. Provide your complete & latest .htaccess in your question and tell me if this .htaccess in DOCUMENT_ROOT or DOCUMENT_ROOT/site?